# Pie plot of grouped dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot, group-by

I want to plot monthly spendings using a pie chart with pandas plotting functions. I was able to create the dataframe that I wanted but I am not able to create a separate pie chart for each month on the dataframe.
This is how I created the dataframe:

```
monthly_expenditure = expenditure_statement.groupby(
        [
            pd.Grouper(key="date", freq="M"),
            pd.Grouper(key="location"),
        ]
    ).sum()
```

This gives me for each month of the year the total amount of money spent at each location, which is correct but now I want to turn each month into a separate pie chart. The slices of the pie chart should be the location.

I tried plotting it using the `df.plot.pie` function but I am not get a new plot for each month. All the rows of the dataframe seem to be collected in one single pie chart.

Comment: `monthly_expenditure.unstack('date').plot.pie()`

Comment: This worked but I had to include the subplots=True parameter in the .pie function. Unfortunately there are a couple years worth of data so all the pie charts visualized together is just a mess. Is it possible to just iterate over each month and create a separate pie chart?

Comment: `subplot=True` plots each group data in a separate subplot.